# Joint distribution of multiple binomial distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

In the picture below, how do they arrive at the joint density function? I understand how Binomial distributions work, but have never seen the joint distribution of them.

The original file can be found here: [Link](http://math.la.asu.edu/~nbrewer/Summer2008/EM_Talk/An_Introduction_to_the_EM_Algorithm4.ppt)

[image: Joint Binomials]

Answer (score 4):

If you have $N$ *independent* random variables with densities $f_1,\ldots,f_N$, then the *joint* density is simply $$
  f(x_1,\ldots,x_N) = f_1(x_1)\cdot\ldots\cdot f_N(x_N)
$$

The join density of $N$ independent random variables with $X_i \sim \textrm{Bin}(m,p)$ is thus $$
  f(x_1,\ldots,x_N) = \prod_{i=1}^N \underbrace{\binom{m}{x_i} p^{x_i}(1-p)^{m-x_i}}_{=\mathbb{P}(X_i=x_i)}
  = p^{\sum_{i=1}^N x_i} (1-p)^{\sum_{i=1}^N (m-x_i)} \prod_{i=1}^N \binom{m}{x_i} \text{.}
$$

Comment: Why is it that in the picture, the big PI has i run from 3 to 5 and not 1 to 5?

Comment: @IcySnow Your question doesn't provide enough context to answer that, I least for me. It probably comes from $x_3,x_4,x_5$ being consideres *known*, but to understand why that's significant one would need to know where all this is supposed to lead to...

Comment: I edited my question to include the original file from which I got the picture. It's on page 8 of the slide.