# Joint distribution of multiple dependent binomial variables

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Taking this example: [Joint distribution of multiple binomial distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397113/joint-distribution-of-multiple-binomial-distributions), how can the joint distribution be written if the data are dependent ?

Comment: have a look at [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0605189)